# Call task's updateProgress

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx, javafx-2, task

I was reading the documentation for the [class Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

```
    final Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() {
            for(int i=0;i<datesAndStudies.length;i++){
                updateProgress(i,datesAndStudies.length);
                DoSomething something = new DoSomething();
                something.VeryLongAndTimeConsumingMethod(i);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

And I notice that updateProgress is protected and workdone/totalwork are both defined as **public final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty**.

Is there a way/workaround to update/call *updateProgress* or edit those values(*workdone/totalwork*) from the method: VeryLongAndTimeConsumingMethod(int i) in the class DoSomething  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if `updateProgress(...)` were public, you'd have to pass a reference to the `Task` to your `DoSomething` class, which creates some really ugly coupling. If you have that level of coupling between your `Task` implementation and your `DoSomething` class, you may as well just define the long, time consuming method in the `Task` subclass itself, and get rid of the other class:

```
final Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        for (int i=0; i<datesAndStudies.length; i++) {
            veryLongAndTimeConsumingMethod(i);
        }
        return null ;
    }

    private void veryLongAndTimeConsumingMethod(int i) {
        // do whatever...
        updateProgress(...);
    }
};
```

To preserve your decoupling, just define a `DoubleProperty` representing the progress in `DoSomething`, and observe it from the `Task`, calling `updateProgress(...)` when it changes:

```
public class DoSomething {
    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper progress = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(this, "progress");
    public double getProgress() {
        return progress.get();
    }
    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty progressProperty() {
        return progress.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
    public void veryLongAndTimeConsumingMethod(int i) {
        // ..
        progress.set(...);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
final Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        for (int i=0; i<datesAndStudies.length; i++) {
            DoSomething something = new DoSomething();
            something.progressProperty().addListener(
                (obs, oldProgress, newProgress) -> updateProgress(...));
            something.veryLongAndTimeConsumingMethod();
        }
    }
}
```