# How to best communicate progress to a View class from a Model class in JavaFx

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX project with MVC component classes.

Handling a particular menu item in the View component results in a FileChooser invocation and the results of this are passed to the Controller for processing by the Model.

This file processing though can last several seconds so I'd like to run it on on another thread and pop up a progress dialog whilst it's running.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701639/call-tasks-updateprogress) shows a possible solution for two separate classes which I *could* adapt to passing the progress status back to the View (managing the progress dialog) from the Model (managing the file processing) via the Controller but it seems an excessively convoluted adaptation.

I'm curious to know if/how other people have developed clean solutions for this whilst keeping the MVC separation?

UPDATE:

This is how I've got the separation at this stage:

View: Acts on menu selection by invoking fileChooser and passing the selected file to the Controller.

Model: Takes file from Controller and invokes firePropertyChange on status variables

Controller: Takes file from View, creates a background activity to invoke the Model activity, monitors the status variables and invokes updateProgress on changes to update progress dialog.

```
public class eeView 
implements Initializable {

 @FXML
 private void openHashdeep() {

 ...
 file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( primaryStage );
 ...     
 notifyReadHashdeepFile( file );             
}

 public void createProgressDialog(String title, String masthead, Worker<?> worker )
 {
     Dialogs.create()
            .owner(primaryStage)
            .title(title)
            .masthead(masthead)
            .showWorkerProgress(worker);                    
 }   


public class eeController 
implements EEListener {

public void readHashdeepFile(File file) {        

     Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() 
     {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() 
            {
                return new Task<Void>() 
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call()
                    throws InterruptedException 
                    {                                                                               
                        try {
                                System.out.println("readHashdeepFile " + file);                         

                                theModel.addPropertyChangeListener( new PropertyChangeListener()
                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                                        String propertyName = e.getPropertyName();

                                        //System.out.println( "Change in " + propertyName + ", now " + (long) e.getNewValue() );

                                        if ( "BytesToProcess".equals(propertyName) ) {
                                            BytesToProcess = (long) e.getNewValue();
                                            System.out.println( "Change in " + propertyName + ", now " + (long) e.getNewValue() );

                                        } 
                                        else if ( "BytesProcessed".equals(propertyName) ) {
                                            BytesProcessed = (long) e.getNewValue();
                                            updateProgress( BytesProcessed, BytesToProcess );
                                        }                   
                                    }                   
                                });

                            theModel.readHashdeepFile( file );          
                        }
                        catch( EEException ex ){        
                            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());            
                            theView.displayErrorMessage( ex.getMessage() );         
                        }

                        // TODO  theModel.removePropertyChangeListener(...);

                        return null;
                    }
                };
          }
     };

     theView.createProgressDialog("Progress Dialog", "Loading file", service );

     service.start();        
}



public class eeModel {

public void readHashdeepFile( File file ) 
throws EEException {

    long BytesToProcess;
    long BytesProcessed;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

        String line;
        String[] word; 
        int lineno = 0;

        List<Filedata> tempData = new ArrayList<Filedata>();

        BytesToProcess = file.length();
        mPcs.firePropertyChange( "BytesToProcess", 0, BytesToProcess );                             

        BytesProcessed = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineno++;
            BytesProcessed += line.length();
            mPcs.firePropertyChange( "BytesProcessed", 0, BytesProcessed ); 
            ...             
        }

        br.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 ...    
}
```

Comment: Needs code.  All I can say from your description is "use a SwingWorker".

Comment: Typically, you bind properties in your view to properties in the model. Your file processing code should then update the model on completion.